# Gson returning null

Tags: java, gson

I am having trouble with JSON, I currently have this class to convert a json response from my api to a object but its returning all the values null -

```java
public class User {

    public String username;

    public User(String username) throws IOException {
        this.username = username;
        URL url = new URL(urlhere);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)");
        String response = ApiRequest.getResponse(connection);
        connection.disconnect();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        gson.fromJson(response, this.getClass());
    }

    public int id;
    public String email;
    public String role;
    public String plan;
    public String planEndDate;

}
```

I am very new to json, please keep this in mind, I may have missed something.

JSON RESPONSE EXAMPLE:

```
{"id":7,"username":"xx","email":"xx","role":"administrator","plan":"xx","planEndDate":"xx"}
```

Comment: your problem is not related to json. you never set those fields to anything else than null, so why would they be something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole network access is not needed here, you could just pass the JSON in a String. A constructor that does network I/O is also a really bad idea anyway, as it's slow and a pain in unit tests.

That said, `gson.fromJson` returns a `User` object, but you never do anything with it; it just goes out of scope.

I'd change the code to something like this:

```
public class User {
    public String username;
    public int id;
    public String email;
    public String role;
    public String plan;
    public String planEndDate;

    public static User findByName(String username) throws IOException {
         String json = downloadUserData(username);
         return new Gson().fromJson(json, User.class);
    }

    public static String downloadUserData(String username) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlhere);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)");
        String response = ApiRequest.getResponse(connection);
        connection.disconnect();
        return response;
    }
}
```

That way you can still build users manually, or download their data from somewhere if you must.

```
User downloaded = User.findByName("me");

User json = new Gson().fromJson("{\"id\": 1, \"username\": \"me\", ... \"}", User.class);

User manually = new User();
manually.username = "me";
manually.email = "me@example.org";
// ...
```